# Referencing two documents to each other

Tags: database-design, mongodb

Is it good practice and or recommended to reference 2 documents to each other using ref? Like this:

```
const FirstDocumentId = mongoose.model(
    'FirstDocumentId',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        coolField: String,
        secondDocumentId: {type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'secondDocumentId'}
    })
);


const SecondDocumentId = mongoose.model(
    'SecondDocumentId',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        someField: String,
        firstDocumentId: {type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'firstDocumentId'}
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

All depends on their relationship. However, the way you describe it implies that this is a 1-to-1 relationship, since each schema refers to the other. Therefore, why not just combine the schemas?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris! The reason I can't do that is cuz they will both contain a lot of fields and I won't always need all fields from `SecondDocumentId` when accessing `FirstDocumentId` and vice versa

Comment: That is a common concern ... what do you mean "a lot of fields" ... we have documents with 200+ fields.

Comment: I don't have anywhere near 200 fields. But the less fields I have the faster it is to read/update/write. And I think it keeps things more organized. Why is this way worse?

Comment: You are introducing unnecessary complexity. What do you mean "the faster it is to read/update/write" - mongodb is incredibly fast, and document field could is not the primary impacter of the time for operations. Are you basing this on what you think is the case or did you do an analysis of CRUD operations with small-field-quantity and large-field-quantity documents?

Comment: If you want it to be "organized" - put what you would have put in the second document in a sub-object within the first document. In other words ... you can make all the secondary document fields properties of a single first-level property in the first document.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between the two collections is one-to-one. Lets consider the two collections as:

*first_coll*:

```
_id: ObjectId,
theId: <string>,
descr: <string>,
// and other fields
```

*second_coll*:

```
_id: ObjectId,
theId: <string>,
name: <string>,
// and other fields
```

The field `theId`, is defined for both the collections, and have the same value. This field establishes the relationship between the collections. And, this field value need to be a unique for each document; this means both collections will have same number of documents.

When you want to query the `first_coll` or `second_coll` individually, use the `theId` field or any other field (like the `_id`) for accessing the documents.

When you want to query the `first_coll` as primary collection, but get some details from the second collection, then you can do a join (left outer join) aggregation `$lookup` query and shape the result document as per your need. Similarly with the `second_coll`.

Identifying what are the primary queries and how they are formed in the application will give better insight to look into aspects and refining the design further.